# Test for master branch changes in Github Post-Receive Hook

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

I am implementing an autobuilder / CI deployer based on Githubs [Post-Receive Hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks). The system should only build and deploy the master branch of the repository; hooks that are triggered by pushes to other branches should be ignored.

However, it is not clear to me how to detect from the [Post-Receive Hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) payload if the "current push" contains any commits in the master branch of the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [JSON payload sent to you by the webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks#the-payload), the `ref` element will be set to `refs/heads/master`.